# Why is this Aggregate not working?

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Post` with many `Tags` where I select that tag `Name`. I just want to output all the tags as simple string.

I get these errors

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDateTime).AsEnumerable().Select(post => new
{
    post.Id,
    post.Title,
    Tags = post.Tags.SelectMany(x => x.Name).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ',' + next) // error
});
```

I've also tried to use `" "` and even storing the delimiter in variable but nothing helps. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @pasty like so? `post.Tags.SelectMany(x => x.Name).Aggregate((current, next) => string.Format("{0} {1}", current, next))` nothing changes, I get same error.

Comment: Yes, but it does not make sense - sorry, i was/am on the wrong track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `SelectMany` with `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

SelectMany flattens queries that return lists of lists, it's like a join shortcut, therefore you get the error. All you need to do is to replace it with Select, here is the code, it should work:

```
var posts = _db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDateTime).AsEnumerable().Select(post => new
{
    post.Id,
    post.Title,
    Tags = post.Tags.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ',' + next) // error
});
```